# Receiving Lots of Spam

Tags: profile

Our online profile forms are receiving lots of spam, even though reCAPTCHA is enabled. Any suggestions? Example form is here: http://insideout180.org/donate/adult-allies-registration-form/

Comment: How much data per record is being submitted? It may not help that none of the fields are required.

Comment: Also are you sure it's from the form submissions - you have your email address easily available in the right sidebar on that page.

Comment: Here's a sample of a spam submission: Submitted For  HenryFutCD HenryFutCD
Date  Sat, 09 Mar 2019 04:25:06 -0500
Contact Summary  http://insideout180.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview&reset=1&cid=5267
Adult Ally Sign-Up
First Name  HenryFutCD
Last Name  HenryFutCD
Email  howyamisu@gmail.com
Phone Number  85174495258
Street Address  Nuwara Eliya
Supplemental Address 1  Nuwara Eliya
City  Nuwara Eliya
State  IA
Zip Code  123142
Group(s)  
What else should we know about you? Volunteer interests, skills, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Please add required fields to your form, at the moment it's possible to submit form with no data and even a spam bot can bypass the CAPTCHA.

Protect also the publicly accessible form with SSL certificate

Comment: The spambots fill in all the fields as it is, so why would making fields required help at all?

Also why would SSL help combat spambots? Certainly there are other reasons to install SSL, but I don't see how should stop spammers.

Comment: It's not to stop spam, it's a must for a public form where users are submitting personal data.  There is simply no reason to not be using SSL these days.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a look at your form (on my iPhone) and the issue is that there is NO reCAPTCHA configured.

In the Profile that you’re exposing in this form -> hit its Settings -> click on its Advanced Settings (fieldset at the bottom of the form) -> check the reCAPTCHA box but most importantly hit that ? to the right of it to get a popup with detailed instructions on how to configure it.